# Rails 3 Nester_Form Gem: How do I customize the template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, nested-forms

I am using the rails 3 gem [nested_forms](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) and would like to change how the default blueprint for insertion is generated. I can not figure out how/where this code would comes from, and how/where I would add code to modify it.

I am currently using a partial for my form:

/app/views/units/_unit.html.haml

```
%tr
  %td=f.text_field :units 
  %td=f.text_field :dispatched
  %td=f.text_field :onscene
  %td=f.text_area  :actions
```

The code snippet that calls the partial:

/app/vies/reports/_form.html.haml

```
...    
%table.units
  %th Unit
  %th Dispatched%th On Scene
  %th Actions
=f.fields_for :units

%p= f.link_to_add "Add a unit", :units
...
```

I have all of the core functionality working, except for the template. That is auto created at run time by the gem. This template results in very simple HTML markup being used for the template.

Which is similar to the following:

```
<div id="units_fields_blueprint" style="display:none">
  <p class="fields">
    <input id="report_units_attributes_new_units_unit" name="report[units_attributes][new_units][unit]" size="30" type="text">
    <input id="report_units_attributes_new_units_dispatched_1i" name="report[units_attributes][new_units][dispatched(1i)]" type="hidden" value="2011">
    ...
  </p>
</div>
```

I would like the blueprint to have the tabular format that is in the partial, I just don't know how to get there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The nested_form gem does not create any templates, it simply gives you the helper to insert your partial, and the javascript to add and remove it dynamically. Unless Ryan has changed it recently.

Comment: I must have been a little unclear, I apologize. What I would like to be able customize is the blueprint (not template) that is generated when a page with a nested for is created. This is seen in the last code block in the original post.

Comment: I am thinking there is something else in play here as I just just double checked some of my apps using the nested form gem. None of them are inserting any blueprint, it only renders the partial exactly as I have it laid out, which is similar to what I think you are expecting.

Comment: Are you sure? When you view the source code from a page rendered using a nested for you do not have a <div id="..._blueprint"> inserted? If not, how are you calling for the partial to be rendered?

Comment: I found, an article http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2010/12/31/dynamically-nesting-deeply-nested-forms.html which talks about how the plugin works, and it talks about the blueprint. I have extracted a small quote: "The nested_form basically creates a blueprint for the nested form fields and places it in a hidden division right after the form. A click on the link created by link_to_add will insert an additional nested form through jQuery after the last nested form of its kind."

Comment: I am using HTML and not HAML, and also just prototype.js and not JQuery, I do not know if this makes a difference in the output. I do not have any <div id="..._blueprint">, it is simply just another <tr> element. I am just calling the partial the same as you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial which contains only a table row, such as listed above will not be valid markup when placed within the blueprint div.

The following code is not valid markup.

```
<div>
  <tr>
    <td>Content</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Certain browsers (chrome for example) will attempt to correct this bad markup, which is done by stripping out the tr and td markup.

To get this type of code to work with nested_form would be complex requiring that the blueprint be created in a javascript string, and would require a modification to the builder to stop automatically surrounding inserted code in a  block of code.

These changes are addressed in [issue #73 for nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/pull/73) which refers to a branch created by the github user elmatou.

Another option to get a similar look and feel is to use divs and spans and create a grid structure using CSS. This is a CSS intensive process, but allows nested_form to be used without requiring alteration.